# Object says it's zeroed on an axis, but it's not. How do I fix?

Tags: axis

I have this object that says it is zeroed out, but it's actually not and I have a reference object to prove it. I believe it started showing this "false zero" because I joined it to another object earlier, moved it,  but then separated it. Is there a way to move this object to the "true zero"?

Comment: It depends on the object, and where you want "zero" to be in it. You could try selectcing the object and (in object mode) from the top of the viewport select `Object > Set Origin >` and then try something like `Origin to geometry` or `Origin to Center of Mass`. That will reset the origin of the object, then you can place it back at `0,0,0` coordinates using the transforms in the `N` tool menu. However, if your object had its transforms modified  (and applied) when you joined it, you may have to reset it manually (by eye).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordinates are linked to origins of objects.
So, *Right click in Object mode > Set Origin > Geometry to Origin* will move the object to its origin which has zeroed coords.

Comment: Thank you! Also, one more question. Do you see Christopher Bennett's answer? Why doesn't it give me the ability to upvote or make his the answer? It doesn't even show the arrows.

Comment: He probably hid it to clean up the site.

Comment: His answer can't be marked as the preferred answer because it was given in the comment section, instead of in the answer section. Only answers given in the answer section can be marked as the preferred answer. Sometimes users give their answers in the comment section when they want to offer something helpful, but don't see their contribution as a full answer. Or sometimes they give simpler answers in the comments section for convenience.